# Upload image to server not working

Tags: php, curl, file-upload, upload, image-uploading

Before I start, I want to clarify that I did extensive research on this but none of the solutions work.

I have been create a app that allow to users upload your images to create an event.

I tried to upload this images to my server, and I received successfully in the response but when I check my directory whether the image is not there, I assume that did not uploaded.

Before I upload the image I check whether the image already exists in folder, to do this I have to create a function using curl to verify that, because function `file_exists` did not working.

I don't know what I have to do more, to get this.
P.S: I'm using backbone.js to build my application.

here my code:
html:

```
<form id="uploadimage" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
            </form>
```

view.js

```
events: {
        'click #guardar' : 'guardarEvento',
        'click #guardarImagem' : 'guardarImagem',
        'change input[type=file]' : 'uploadFile'    
    },

guardarImagem: function(){

    var fileInput = document.getElementById('uploadimage');
    console.log(new FormData(fileInput));
    $.ajax({
        url: "js/views/ajax_php_file.php", // Url to which the request is send
        type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
        data: new FormData(fileInput), // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
        contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
        cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
        processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
        success: function(data){   // A function to be called if request succeeds
            console.log(data);
        }
    }); 
},
```

ajax_php_file.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES["file"]["type"])){
    $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");
    $temporary = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $file_extension = end($temporary);

    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    ) && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 100000)//Approx. 100kb files can be uploaded.
    && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br/><br/>";
        }else{
            if (file_exists("http://www.***/webtools/ondequemvaiver/agora/img/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])){
                echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " <span id='invalid'><b>already exists.</b></span> ";
            }else{
                $sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; // Storing source path of the file in a variable
                $targetPath = "http://www.***/webtools/ondequemvaiver/agora/img/".$_FILES['file']['name']; // Target path where file is to be stored

                move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath) ; // Moving Uploaded file


                echo "<span id='success'>Image Uploaded Successfully...!!</span><br/>";
                echo "<br/><b>File Name:</b> " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
                echo "<b>Type:</b> " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
                echo "<b>Size:</b> " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
                echo "<b>Temp file:</b> " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo "<span id='invalid'>***Invalid file Size or Type***<span>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you check error into apache log files ?
Your $targetPath seems strange

Comment: `$targetPath = "http://` that shouldn't be an http call, but a path to. `$targetPath = "/var/user/httpdocs/webtools/ondequemvaiver/agora/img/` as an example. Read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- I change my targetPath but still not working :/

Comment: Make sure the folder(s) have proper permissions set to write to. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: I'm not very good with Ajax/JS but this `'change input[type=file]' : 'uploadFile'` the second parameter. If that is for an "id", then shouldn't that be `'change input[type=file]' : 'file'` as per `id="file"`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I change the targetPath as you said, and then give the permissions and now it works :). I don't known that the targetPath shouldn't contains "http://". Thanks

Comment: You're welcome and I'm glad that it worked out for you, *cheers*. You can post your own answer if you wish or delete the question.

Comment: Or I can post an answer and you can accept it to close the question. The choice is yours ;-)

Comment: You can post an answer, no problem :)

Comment: It has been done, *cheers*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use a system path when using [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) rather than an `http://` call.

I.e.:

```
$targetPath = "/var/user/httpdocs/webtools/ondequemvaiver/agora/img/...
```

or

```
$targetPath = "webtools/ondequemvaiver/agora/img/...
```

depending on the location of the script's execution.

You also need to make sure that the folder(s) has proper permissions in order to be written to.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.